# Attempting to list data using ID from a particular table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one table which stores user info, including the username.

Another table contains a list of user id's and the user id's of those that they have favorited.

I am trying to figure out the query for listing the usernames of those that user id 1 has favorited.

In my query, assuming that I am uid 1, I need the usernames of uid 3 and 5, but instead
in sqlfiddle I am attempting to join them but I keep getting my username, cjaredrun, instead of the matched usernames for each favorite.

You can see what I have been trying here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5836/1

Any guidance appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a simple join:

```
SELECT u.username FROM fav_user f
JOIN users u ON u.uid = f.matchuid
WHERE f.uid = 1
ORDER BY datetime
```

Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/527b7/1).

Output:

```
| USERNAME |
|----------|
|    jolet |
|     jane |
```